# OMNET++ Wireless Communication with mobility

Tags: omnet++

I want to implement a wireless project with mobility. The broadcasting node should send the packets when the mobile receiver is in the range only. Otherwise they should just hold the packets to themselves.
I have implemented the wireless project with mobility. But cannot control the broadcast of the messages this way. Can anyone please tell me how to do this exactly. I am really in need of this. Thank You.